# How to use a post title as the page title for the browser in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I can't seem to figure out how to turn a Post title on the blog app I am building into the page title. Below is the helper I am using and the line of code in the application layout. I would like to know what I need to do in order to have each post title also be the page title. Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Application helper

```
 module ApplicationHelper
   def full_title(page_title)
     base_title = "Business Name"
     if page_title.empty?
       base_title
     else
       "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
     end
   end
 end
```

Application Layout

```
<title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
```

show.html.erb

```
<h1><%= @post.title %></h1>
  <p>
    <%= @post.body.html_safe %>
  </p>
<%= link_to 'Back to Posts', posts_path %>
```

Comment: You can use content_for on the page you want to specify title
eg: `<% content_for(:title, "My title") %>`

Comment: @shiva added the view file per your suggestion

Comment: @jbmyid thank you for your response. I still don't understand how I could use your suggestion to get each post title to show up as the page title since this would be included in the show.html.erb template?

Comment: @KDark11 yes, you have to add in your show.html.erb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your posts/show.html.erb view

```
<% content_for :title, @post.title %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your **application.html.erb**

```
<head>
  <%= yield :title %>
</head>
```

In your view

```
<% content_for :title do %>
  <title><%=full_title(@post.title)%></title>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

As commented By @jbmyid,use `content_for` like this

```
def full_title(page_title)
  base_title = "Business Name"
  if page_title.empty?
  content_for :title, base_title.to_s
  else
  "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
end
```

use it in your application layout as like:

```
<title><%= yield(:title) %></title>
```

then call it in your templates:

```
<% full_title(@post.title %>
```